# jQuery UI hiding not taking effect for early DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement simple hide/show functionality using jQuery. I have two groups of boxes: A and B. I want to be able to click one button to see just the boxes from group A, and a different button to show just group B. This should not depend on what's happened on the page previously, or the order of button presses.

Based on the official basic code sample for [the jQuery UI `hide()` function](https://jqueryui.com/hide/), I'm using a strategy where a button click has two effects: first, hide all the boxes from both groups, and second, reveal the boxes from the group I want to see. There's also a button to show all boxes, which basically functions as a reset.

Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't (MVCE snippet below). When I start from a fresh page load or a reset, I can click the button to show group A, and it's fine. When I click on the button to show group B, though, the group A buttons stay on the screen. Or, from a fresh page/reset, I can click on the group B button and see just boxes from group B, then the group A button and see just boxes from group A, but then I can't get back to just group B.

A bit of investigation with the console and additional groups has revealed that this has something to do with DOM order. I can always select any given group that I want, to start with, but things get messed up if I then try to show a group that appears earlier in the DOM.

What's causing the current behavior, and how can I fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggleAll").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
  });

  $("#toggleA").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').hide('clip', {}, 1000);
    $('.groupA').removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
  });

  $("#toggleB").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').hide('clip', {}, 1000);
    $('.groupB').removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Show boxes of type:</p>
<button id="toggleAll">Show all</button>
<button id="toggleA">Show group A</button>
<button id="toggleB">Show group B</button>

<hr />

<div id="a1" class="box groupA">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box A1</p>
</div>
<div id="a2" class="box groupA">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box A2</p>
</div>

<div id="b1" class="box groupB">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box B1</p>
</div>
<div id="b2" class="box groupB">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box B2</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroRomero it is already. `$(function() { ... })` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Thanks for the point, I deleted my comment to avoid errors. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Follow-up to this question: [Early DOM elements not hiding when using effects with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193146/early-dom-elements-not-hiding-when-using-effects-with-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try it without all your additional options and use the simple `hide()` and `show()`, or in your case the `fadeIn()`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggleAll").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').fadeIn();
  });

  $("#toggleA").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.groupA').fadeIn();
  });

  $("#toggleB").on("click", function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.groupB').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Show boxes of type:</p>
<button id="toggleAll">Show all</button>
<button id="toggleA">Show group A</button>
<button id="toggleB">Show group B</button>

<hr />

<div id="a1" class="box groupA">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box A1</p>
</div>
<div id="a2" class="box groupA">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box A2</p>
</div>

<div id="b1" class="box groupB">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box B1</p>
</div>
<div id="b2" class="box groupB">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>Text for box B2</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh. Did not know those existed. (Can you tell I'm brand new to this?) I'm still curious _why_ my original code didn't work, though, so I can avoid other problems in the future that have the same root cause.

Comment: `hide()` sets the element style to `display:none;` .. `removeAttr('style')` removes all style information of the element. `fadeIn()` sets the style to `display:block`

I can't tell exactely what is the problem here, but in my opinion it has to do with the `removeAttr('style')` ... maybe the DOM is not able to set new style attribute in the same turn afterwards